# How to structure modules?

Tags: module, package

On my first attempt to create a program that's too big to fit into one source file, I keep running into problems with separating it into several. For example, what should I do if one module is to be used by several other modules, which end up being included into one another. Say, linear_algebra.cpp (or .py or whatever) requires tensor_operations.cpp, and they both require matrix_operations.cpp. Should I include matrix_operations.cpp into both other files, or just into one or what? And what if then I add matrix_operations into some other module, that on some point suddenly turns up requiring linear_algebra as well?
This whole business keeps confusing me constantly. Sometimes I figure it out, but there has to be a "proper" way, so that you don't have to figure out by yourself.

So, where can I get a manual on how to do this sort of stuff properly (or at least what do they call it, because google does not understand me when I say "this sort of stuff")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to avoid **cyclic dependencies**, which is the key term you want to search for.

For example if you have modules A and B and you find that A needs to refer to B **and** B needs to refer to A then you have a cyclic dependency between A and B. (In other words, if you drew the relationships between modules as a graph with arrows showing the dependencies, there would be a pair of arrows between A and B.)

The solution is to identify the bit of code in A that's needed by B, refactor that bit out into a new module C and then refer to C from both A and B. (This means that B doesn't need to refer to A any more.)

So you go from

```
A <----> B
```

to

```
A -----> B
|        |
\/       |
   /     |
C  ------
   \
```

By doing this, you go from a few large modules to many smaller modules with looser coupling between them. This, in turn, should make your code easier to maintain and reuse.

Comment: That's not just about cyclic dependencies (although thanks for clarifying at least that). The question is more general: how to arrange and structure program modules in a general case? Is there a full manual?

Comment: Check out books such as *Code Complete* or *The Pragmatic Programmer*. These will give you some principles to follow, such as loose coupling and high cohesion. But there's no "paint by numbers" solution -- every program is different.